# Rails Gem install fails after Rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

So when I run:

```
$ rails new mywebapp
```

I get the following error:

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
```

This is despite installing rbenv via Homebrew.

I have added the following to ~/.bash_profile

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

And installed a version of Ruby.

Running:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Gives me:

```
/Users/myusername/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Im not sure where to go from here. Hoping someone can help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: Are you actually using the rbenv ruby that you installed (e.g. `rbenv global 2.1.1` to set 2.1.1 as the global default). If not, you may still be using the system ruby.

Comment: @DylanMarkow running `$rbenv verions` returns `system
* 2.0.0-p247 (set by /Users/myusername/.rbenv/version)` and `$rbenv global` returns `2.0.0-p247`.

Comment: and have you run `gem install rails` after installing rbenv? It sounds like maybe it's still trying to use `/usr/bin/rails`?

Comment: @DylanMarkow I think I bungled the rails install as running `gem install rails` seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you @DylanMarkow for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments to the original question, the answer was that the system-installed `rails` executable was being used instead of the rbenv version. The fix was to run:

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with Dylan on the problem, I think that the best solution is to set explicitly an **Rbenv global version** using `rbenv global 2.1.1`
And then reinstalling bundler on that version.

`gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash`

This worked good for me.
Hope it helps.